# Who are all the people at the funeral?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, ending, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame* near the end we attend Iron Man funeral but there were few faces I was not able to recognize. I do recognize the kid from Iron Man 3 and the Avengers but some civilians were getting a brief glimpse which I can't recognize.

Is there a list of all attendees from the funeral?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In approximate order of appearance:

- Pepper Potts & Morgan Stark
- Happy Hogan
- James Rhodes (War Machine)
- Steve Rogers (Captain America)
- Peter Parker (Spider-Man) & Aunt May
- Thor
- Bruce Banner (Hulk)
- Steven Strange (Dr. Strange) & Wong
- Scott Lang (Ant-Man)
- Hope Van Dyne (Wasp)
- Dr. Hank Pym & Janet Van Dyne
- Peter Quill (Star-Lord), Rocket Racoon, Groot, Drax, Mantis & Nebula (no Gamora)
- T'Challa (Black Panther) & Okoye & Shuri
- Clint Barton (Hawkeye) & Family
- Bucky Barnes (Winter Soldier / White Wolf)
- Wanda Maximoff (Scarlet Witch)
- Sam Wilson (Falcon)
- Harley Keener (the kid from Iron Man 3)
- Thaddeus Ross (Secretary of State)
- Maria Hill
- Carol Danvers (Captain Marvel)
- Nick Fury

[**Source**](https://www.denofgeek.com/us/movies/marvel/280745/avengers-endgame-tony-stark-ending-scene)

Comment: Thanks for Harley Keener information. I first had the impression of seeing Peter Parker twice.

Comment: I recognized the kid but couldn't place him until I looked it up afterwards. (All the others have been in multiple movies...)