# Why wasn't Valkyrie present at the funeral?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

Was watching *Avengers: Endgame* one more time and noticed that Valkyrie (Tessa Thompson) wasn't present at the funeral at the end.

[This answer lists all the people who attended the funeral including that kid from Iron Man 3](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/100152/5315). So it looked strange to me that Tessa wasn't a part of it.

Valkyrie has decent amount of screen time in the movie & also has a scene after the funeral where Thor makes her the leader of Asagardians.

So, why wasn't she part of the funeral? Any comment from Russo Brothers or Tessa Thompson?

Comment: It's possible that Valkyrie is busy now in Asgard (on Earth)

Answer (score 11):

### Because she didn't know Tony Stark

**....she never met him.**

While it could be argued that she *might* have attended to honor a fallen hero of the final battle, Valkyrie has never met Tony Stark before and certainly couldn't be considered a close friend.

Thor certainly attended as friend of Tony and representative of (New) Asgard but she wasn't made ruler of Asgard until *after* the funeral / memorial but this seemed to be only for people who knew and/or were friends of Tony.

Comment: Hmm. Fair point. But Hank & his wife & the Wasp was also there at the funeral. They didn't know Tony. In fact they had Michelle Pfeiffer just in this one scene

Comment: True but Scott Lang did know Tony so it's logical that they would attend with him.

Comment: but same logic applies to Thor & Valkyrie no

Comment: Not really..Valkyrie isn't family but a lot of people didn't attend so trying to isolate individual circumstances isn't really overly helpful.

Comment: afaik other named characters that didn't attend are Ned(Peter's friend), Scott's daughter, M'baku, & Korg. Am I missing anyone else. Apart from Scott's daughter, other 3 I mentioned Korg, M'baku & Ned not being there makes sense for obvious reasons

Comment: Also, Hank Pym probably knew Howard Stark so he was attending the funeral of his friend's son, that's not weird.

Comment: @KharoBangdo Korg was busy with his next revolution

Comment: @Vishwa, or he was busy arguing with Noobmaster again...

Comment: @BladeWraith Valkyrie **is** Noobmaster69.  Think about it.  All the pieces fall together.